# StructureMap rules for different namespaces

Tags: c#, structuremap

My scenario is:

Two different parts (ASP.NET MVC Areas) of my project need the same constructor injection as Singleton but different instances setup slightly differently.

E.g.

Site Area = its own singleton

Admin Area = its own singleton

Could this be achieved via StructureMap? The parts of the project are in different namespaces.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question. Is it that Site area need SomeDependency and Admin are need another type of SomeDependency, and both the SomeDependency should be singletons? Or is it that Site area and Admin area are both singletons and need the same dependency as a singleton?

Comment: The first. Admin and Site need different SomeDependency as singletons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you crate one singleton as the default and one as a named instance. And on those places you need the named instance you map up your dependencies to used the named instance instead of the default.

```
Container container = new Container(x => {
      x.For<ISomeDependency>().Singleton().Use<SomeDependency>(); // User
      x.For<ISomeDependency>().Singleton().Add<SomeDependency>().Named("admin");
});
```

In the example above "Use<>" marks the default, while "Add<>" is adding an named instance.

This will get you your default:

```
container.GetInstance<ISomeDependency>();
```

While this one will get you your named instance:

```
container.GetInstance<ISomeDependency>("admin");
```